# What are some alternatives to Samba?

Tags: untagged

What are some alternatives to Samba? Please provide the OS and Vendor name.

Also, what support is available for the product in your answer?

The client machines range from Windows XP to Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/default.aspx)?

Seriously, as far as I've seen, Samba is really all that's out there for CIFS file sharing from *nix servers.

Is there something specific that you don't like about Samba?

Comment: `Is there something specific that you don't like about Samba?` Long story. Can't get into it. Sorry. Thannk you for the answer though. I didn't realize that Samba was such an established standard.

Comment: Fair enough. If you have frustrations with Samba, perhaps you could post another question about them. It's quite likely that someone here could help you get things sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

Novell OES2. They have their own CIFS stack and eDirectory can act as a AD DC.